# Pandas set row values on dataframe subset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have a MWE that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b'], 'B':['c','d']})
```

I want to replace the values in column B with a string, if the respective values in column A are equal to 'a'. I've tried a few things:

```
In [27]: test[test['A']=='a']['B'] = 'REPLACEMENT'

In [28]: test
Out[28]:
   A  B
0  a  c
1  b  d
```

and:

```
In [30]: test.ix[test['A']=='a','B'].values.fill('REPLACEMENT')

In [31]: test
Out[31]:
   A  B
0  a  c
1  b  d
```

None of them seem to work. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You should have gotten an error message after your [27] command warning you what you were doing wrong and pointing at a solution. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I did, I perhaps wrongly omitted it - I was just showing my logic. I'm using 16.2.

Comment: The error message described the problem, recommended a solution, and gave the URL for a long discussion which explains what's going on with the solution and why assignment using chained indexing doesn't work.  It's worth reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [64]:
test.B.loc[test.A == 'a'] = 'Replacement'
test
Out[64]:
    A   B
0   a   Replacement
1   b   d
```

Comment: This works but I get the warning: `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`, is this of concern?

Comment: ok no problem , try using `test.B.loc[test.A == 'a'] = 'Replacement'` instead